# Calling External REST api behind proxy using Request module

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request, http-headers

I am trying to call external API using request module, it is working properly when I'm calling API hosted locally but no success while calling external API. Note: I'm behind proxy which may be the issue

**Code**

```
app.get('/Get', function(req, res){

request.get('https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',

function(error, response, body) {

 if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        res.send(response.body);}
 else {
        res.json(error);
    }
});
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log("server is running at 8080");
```

It is working properly if I'm calling local API as bellow:

```
request.get('http://localhost:8080/hello',
```

Answer (score 1):

Proxy was the issue, PFB solution for how to set proxy and add x-api-key header

```
request({uri:'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request', proxy:'http://proxy.server.com', 
headers:{
'x-api-key':'asdfasdfsda'}
},
```